# C# Returning BadRequest looses my custom message

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a controller method declared:

```
[HttpPut] public async Task<IActionResult> Put(NewBookingViewModel value)
```

then

in my error handler I have:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError(ex, " Error amending in viewbooking");
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    response.ReasonPhrase = ex.Message;
    return BadRequest(response);

}
```

in my Blazor component I call the method:

```
response = await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("api/ViewBooking", newBooking);
```

then dropping through I try to get the message with:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("Could not save - please try again or contact your administrator.");
 sb.AppendLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
```

But ReasonPhrase as been overwritten with the default for BadRequest.

How should I be returning my error so that I do not loose the text.

Comment: Either do `return response;` or (better) do `return BadRequest(ex.Message);`. Don't do both, because `BadRequest()` will create the `HttpResponseMessage` for you.

Comment: I cannot do `return response` it redlines and if i do `return BadRequest(ex.Message)` my message is still overwritten with the Default

Comment: The string you pass to `BadRequest(string)` will not be used as the reason phrase. It will be part of the response content. The reason phrase is [not intended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) to be used for detailed error messages.

Comment: If you're adamant about misusing the reason phrase you'll have to return the manually created `HttpResponseMessage` and change the controller method's return type accordingly (i.e. `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`).

Comment: Thank you for putting me in the right direction. Adding `var returnVal = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var error= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpResponseMessage>(returnVal);` to my client get's me the value